# Is this gas line grounding OK?

Tags: code-compliance, natural-gas

We had the gas line to our kitchen disconnected and capped off.

The gas line for the heating is still connected and in use.

The grounding wire for all the gas lines was connected to the kitchen pipe.

The guy who did the work installed a jumper wire to connect the rest of the gas lines back to the kitchen pipe to restore the grounding.

I would have expected him to extend the ground wire and connect it directly to the remaining gas pipes.

Is this OK?

Completed job:

[image]

- The main gas connection comes in from the left.
- The gas line for the heating goes up on the right side of the picture.
- The kitchen gas line goes down and into the wall at floor level.  That's also where the ground wire is located.

Detail "jumper wire:"

[image]

Detail "ground wire:"

[image]

I'm fairly sure the pipe is capped off properly.

I'm concerned that the grounding might not be to standard.

It seems to me that the ground wire should be connected directly to the pipes it is intended to protect rather than indirectly over a couple of clamps, a section of pipe, and a jumper wire.

This is in Germany, if that makes any difference in the expected standards.

---

This **not** using the gas pipe as the  electrical ground for the house.

This is tying the gas lines to the ground wire of the house to protect against shorts to the gas line and lightning.

The house itself has a properly installed grounding system that is connected to the breaker box.  The cable from the floor runs back to the ground in the breaker box.

Comment: Presumably, the house has 'proper' grounding & this is just a safety tie-in, same as your water supply?

Comment: @Tetsujin:  Yes.  The cable coming out of the floor is tied to the electrical ground for the house and the electrical wiring.

Comment: Secondary bonding regs are pretty complicated. I'm in the UK so I can't say for Germany, except that "it looks OK to me" at a glance. The main bond should be within 600mm of the electric mains, but that's not always possible.  If you're worried, get an electrician to have a look. Based on UK spec, the cable should be 6mm or larger, strictly it should be green/yellow, but it's pretty obvious what it is even without that. There's a fairly mind-numbing precis of the UK regs at https://electrical.theiet.org/wiring-matters/years/2018/73-november-2018/myth-busters-2/

Comment: I presume your concern is about the installation of the "jumper", not the "ground" at floor level. It appears that the floor level ground was preexisting and the jumper was added to electrically bridge the air gap in the metal piping. If you weren't concerned about the ground connection before this work was done, why would you be concerned about the jumper now? It appears (from your pics) to be done in the same standard & method that the original ground was attached. Would you feel better if the wire ran all the way to the floor?

Comment: It is only the jumper that concerns me.  Safety stuff is not the same as functional stuff.  As it is, the jumper electrically connects things just fine.  Safety stuff is about non-obvious things that only matter in weird circumstances.  It doesn't matter until something goes wrong, then some little detail makes the difference between "bad day" and "total catastrophe."

Comment: @JRE -- what size of wire was used for the jumper?